# Why Spring mail does not recognize my Gmail account?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, gmail

In my SpringBoot application i'm using Spring mail to send emails from a Gmail account (i connected through an app password). It was working fine, but after a time (about a week), it stopped working and i got an error telling me thanks username and password didn't match. After i connected to my Gmail account to check if the app password is still active, it started working again.

After another week, it happened again.

**My question is :** is there any validity time for the application password ? Can i increase it  ? Why is it doing this ? How can i solve this ?

**The error** : 534 5.7.9 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WebLoginRequired k18sm5238866wms.1 - gsmtp ] with root cause ...

**application.properties** :

spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com

spring.mail.port=587

spring.mail.username= my email

spring.mail.password= the app password

spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true

spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true

**Thank you for your help**